# Tableview やボタンの選択不可時のグレーアウトについて

Tags: swift, ios, swift3

swiftにてアプリ作成しています。

TableViewやボタンを選択不可にする方法は調べるとわかったのですが
 グレーアウトにする方法がわかりません。

今は無理やりバックグランドのカラーとタイトル色を変更していますが
 何かほうほうないのでしょうか？

特にTableviewではアイコンを設定しているため、上記方法では不可能で困っています。
 （グレーアウト版のアイコンを作成する必要がある？）

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: グレーアウトしたいのはUITableView全体ですか？それともセルごとですか？また、iOSでは無効状態を表すのにグレーアウトではなく半透明化がよく使用されます（Tint Colorで表示されるものはTint Colorをグレーにしてから半透明化）。必要なのはグレーアウトですか、それとも無効状態を表現することですか？

Answer (score 1):

私がみたことあるのはcellの上にあらかじめ薄いグレーのアルファが付いているものを置いといて、処理でhiddennを分けるというものでした。参考になれば嬉しいです。